# How can I get this simple API fetch call work?

Tags: reactjs, api, use-effect

I am a new React developer. trying to use hooks to call on an API and show the data on screen(after that will try to mess with pagination and filtering results) however for some reason the fetch call does not work , It would work when I show it in Postman but not in my app

```
***main state***

const [apiData, setApiData] = useState({})

***my use Effect hook***

useEffect(() => {

async function getMusicData(){
const music = await fetch('theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/523532/searchalbum.php?s=daft_punk')
.then(res => res.json())
setApiData(music)
console.log(apiData)
}
console.log(apiData)
getMusicData()
},[])

***my rendering attempt***

return (
<Router>
<Navbar />
{dataApi.map((s, i) => (

))}
</Router>
);
```

again(I get a red squiggly under the brackets also!)[showing the red squiggly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4yGA.png):

[Showing API call results in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W5Wk.png)

[console.log(apiData/music) gets me this also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiEJs.png)

Let me know if I can provide you with anything more, I am trying to understand why it wouldn't work in the first place!
appreciate your response

Comment: Your promise is wrong.  When using `await`, you do not need to use `.then`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly your url is wrong. Your fetch url should have https

```
https://theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/523532/searchalbum.php?s=daft_punk
```

so, if you use async keyword this mean fetch will work asynchronous so you dont need **then()** function.

You should like this

```
 const music = await fetch(
    "https://theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/523532/searchalbum.php?s=daft_punk"
  );
  const response = await music.json();
```

then you should use your **setApiData()**

```
  setApiData(response);
```

if you add **console.log(apiData)** here you cant see anything. Because your setApiData() function is asynchronous so, you can see it at next render.

> I get a red squiggly under the brackets also!

I think, it's about the spacing between parentheses. You should add html element (div,span,etc...)

Finally, i fix your code. You can check it.

```
export default function App() {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getMusicData() {
      const music = await fetch(
        "https://theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/523532/searchalbum.php?s=daft_punk"
      );
      const response = await music.json();

      setApiData(response.album);
    }
   
    getMusicData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {apiData.map((s) => (
        <div key={s.idAlbum}>{s.strAlbum}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-rgb-3zzo3f?file=/src/App.js:395-401

Comment: ok, first thank you very much for the detailed response @BIRKAN. somehow it works and it does not . I made a few changes to my code since yesterday as well. I am very confused now. same code you have in the sandbox that works, fails at my app and returns nothing. the fetch call returns the response sometimes when I refresh the page and sometimes it does not

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-saha-nknum6?file=/src/App.js:0-1022
I am a beginner to react and very confused now. I copy pasted my code to sandbox and it worked after I added apiData to the useEffect dependency array but it also keeps on fetching.
what I am trying to do is to capture the user Input now and add it to the api call.
problem is I don't know If I should move the api call to the handleChange function.

Comment: Your codesandbox url is not working. You should'nt add apiData to the useEffect. it's causes infinite loop in the fetch process. You can use useCallBack hook for fetching. If you send your code again we can fix it.

Comment: I keep getting all these errors with webpack v5 not supporting polyfills on my end. can't find a straight forward solution/fix that works here. I get these errors when I try to add a form or create a function that has e.preventDefault() . not sure what's going on here. react sometimes is like walking on egg shells. https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-saha-nknum6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: One more thing, I tried downgrading webpack to version 4.69 and react to version 16.13.0 but also to no avail, there is three pages ow scrolling down the screen of polyfills errors . the moment I take the form out and just rely on an input byitself it goes away

Comment: Just in case you are still gonna take a look.
this is my updated codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-saha-nknum6?file=/src/App.js
right now I got to the point where I console.log(respone) and get the result in the console but I can't map them for some reason !! it throws an error

Comment: Your apidata is array but you gave a object. You can't map empty object. map function only used with arrays. https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-forest-k9fozi if you press search it will work.

Answer (score 0):

[Reference doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3qIw.png)

Remove the ".then" keyword, no need for that.

```
 const music = await fetch('theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/523532/searchalbum.php?s=daft_punk');
```

After this line just write like this:

```
 let response = await music.json();
```